# React-Redux vs shouldComponentUpdate Rendering Optimization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, redux, react-redux

The React-Redux project I am working on handles a group of participants currently organized in a JavaScript object like a map with key:value pair defined as participantId:participant.

I am receiving updates in terms of individual participants, so the program should have exact knowledge of what to re-render.

The components are currently setup such that the parent component is connected to the Redux state, and the participants object is converted into an array and passed down to its children's props.

Every time the update action passes through the reducer, it generates a new state, which fails mapStateToProp's shallow comparison checks and triggers a re-render of the parent component and child components.

Re-rendering the entire list of child components negates the purpose of receiving updates for one participant at a time. If possible, I would like to re-render only the specific child component that has updated and re-render the entire list only when a child is added/removed.

Can I do this with React-Redux? Especially when I'm storing the participants as a mutable data when Redux encourages me not to? Or should I be looking into using ShouldComponentUpdate and ditch Redux?

Comment: Since you have all the participants stored by id in your redux state, I would recommend you to just pass the id down to the child components. Then connect each child to that specific id in redux. Let the reducer do its job, which is to update the minimal piece of state that needs to be changed.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. How would the data being passed to both the parent and children work in this case? It looks like my Redux state needs to keep a list of id's (passed to parent) and the list of participants (child chooses participant with ID given by parent).

Comment: The parent component is already connected to redux state, as you say, right? So it has access to the object (map) containing all the participants. When you render the children, rather than converting the object to an array, just create an array containing all the participant ids. Send the id as a prop to the children. Then (I assume you have a specific component to render a participant) connect the Participant component to the redux store, and use the id to find the correct participant. Also be sure to add an action to update one specific participant by id.